# Do NOT add Storybook to peerDependencies - Nx Angular (ng-packagr)

Tags: storybook, nrwl, ng-packagr, nomachine-nx

*Background:*

I have an Nx workspace with a single Angular library (and its e2e application). The library exports UI Components as separate entry points as well as assets (e.g. stylesheets) via `ng-packagr@15.1.2`.

My source folder's `peerDependencies` have two `@fontsource/...` entries and nothing else.

`Storybook (v6.5)` is added to the `workspace's` and NOT the library(!)'s `package.json` as a `devDependency`. My `tsconfig.lib.ts` (and by extension the `tsconfig.lib.prod.ts`) excludes `**/*.stories.ts`.

*Problem:*

One of the .stories.ts files has the following code: `import type { Args, StoryContext } from '@storybook/csf';`

When listing peer dependencies compile-time, this should be ignored for two reasons:

1. It is explicitly imported as `type`; and
2. It is explicitly ignored in the relevant `tsconfig`.

Yet, when my library builds, `@storybook/csf` is added to the **compiled** `peerDependencies`.
If I delete the import statement above, `@storybook/csf` is NOT added to the **compiled** `peerDependencies`.

*Question:*

Can somebody explain how I can prevent Storybook modules from becoming peer dependencies without

- deleting their (type) imports from my stories' code? and without
- deleting .stories.ts files before building and publishing the library?

Thanks!